# Laravel 5.1 Delete a row from database

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am trying to delete a category by clicking on a button

Blade:

```
<td class="center"><a href="{{URL::to('/deletecat/'.$category->name) }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/deletecat/{name}','CategoryController@delete');
```

Controller:

```
 public function delete($name)
    {

        category::find($name)->delete();

        return Redirect::route('managecategory');

    }
```

but I am getting an error while clicking on a button that

```
Call to a member function delete() on a non-object
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `category::find($name)` is the problem here. Are you sure it's returning a valid response? Do a `dd(category::find($name))` see what it spits out.

Comment: its returning null as a output

Comment: Well there's your problem. Odds are `$name` doesn't exist in the database. Make sure it's there. And for future cases do something like `$record = category::find($name); if(null !== $record){//do stuff here}`

Comment: but i am having a field name as name in database

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `::find($id)` method expects `$id` to be a number, the primary key of the row you want to find.

If you want to delete a row by name, you should use the following code:

```
category::where('name', $name)->delete();
```

Comment: `find()` always finds by `primary key` regardless of type.

Answer (score 0):

In your view:
it has to be a form to submit a POST request like below:

```
    <form  action="/deletecat/{{$data->id}}" method="post">
            @csrf
            @method('DELETE')
        <input type="submit" value="delete " >
    </form>
```

Because this is POST Request has to use csrf and delete action.

In your route, it has be with delete() method,followwing with the controller.

```
Route::delete('/deletecat/{name}', 'CategoryController@destory');
```

In the controller:

```
 public function destory($name)
{

    category::find($name)->delete();

    return Redirect::route('managecategory');

}
```

This is how laravel name format role:
[image]

Comment: Please share more details - why should changing the name of that method help? Is there any magic behind naming the routes?

Comment: It is how laravel name the action and controller, I guess it will be easy to cooperate with other developers.

Comment: This would certainly make the code more standard, but it doesn't explain the problem they were having, which was given an answer 6 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

The error is obviously because of the returned NON-OBJECT.

> ::find($name) returns an empty object or null

This is because the search was empty.

Make sure name is the primary key in order to use find.

Otherwise:

> use ::where('name', $name)->delete();

or:

> ::where('name','=', $name)->delete();

*I pointed `=` because if you ever need to search different than `=` use `>=` `<>` and so on...

Secondly, it is not very important to use `destroy`. It is recommended but not a must-have!